# iOS Rich Push Notification Design

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

[image]

Hi I am new to iOS and push notification,I am using Amazon SNS. Is it possible to design a notification in iOS  as given in screenshot. I am already using Notification extension or Notification Extension Services but the extension allows u to add title,subtitle,body,one image attachemet only.

Comment: You can design screen as attached within your app, but in NotificationCenter, you can only only things which is already provided by Apple.  You can't customize like your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @Surjeet. Yes I have read the apple Json Payload doc. But I was not sure that whether we can design the push notification as in screenshot or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best possible solution to this would be if you can render and image similar to the screenshot you sent removing the approve deny buttons.
Add send the image url in the payload of the push notification.
Make sure you add "mutable-content" : 1 in the aps dict.
You can check tutorials to send Images in Rich notifications.

Secondly the approve deny buttons can be added using actionable customisations.

Comment: Yes! we can send the image url and using Notification extension we can show the image in notification, right. But the data in the screenshot will be dynamic. So we can not show the dummy image. Thanks @Mukul

Comment: Yes.  That's why I said. Render in the image from backend.  So what you do is. Write a code in the backend to generate the image with the given content which is dynamic.  And send it as the attached url. This the best possible solution I could think of. If you really need to show such an interface to the users.

Comment: Yeah! It might be helpful.